# Weather information google-maps-api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, weather-api, google-weather-api

I have a google maps api , and I have included the weather api as well in that.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=weather">
    </script>
```

```js
// Assigning map to its variable
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
        temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT
    });
    weatherLayer.setMap(map);
```

Now I just need to display windspeed on click of a marker regarding a place.
But I am not able to find any methods exposed for displaying the wind speed.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "weather" library or weather API that is part of the Google Maps Javascript API v3.  There **used** to be a weather layer but per the documentation on [archive.org from March 18, 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150318080244/https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers) it was deprecated in 2014 and turned off last June:

> The Weather and Cloud layers allow you to add weather forecasts and cloud imagery to your map.
>
> **Note: The Weather and Cloud layers have been deprecated as of June 4, 2014. They will cease functioning on June 4, 2015.**